# Android: arraylist of markers on google maps android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I have created an array-list of objects and I;m trying to display them on a google map, but I keep getting a NullPointerException.

**MapsActivity:**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

public static final String retrieveP = "RETRIEVE_POI";
public static final String retrieveAP = "RETRIEVE_ALL_POIs";
public static final String parseDocPoi = "PARSE_DOC_POI";
final String dbname = "myapp";
private String docId = "123";
private Manager manager;
private Database couchDb;
Poi poi;
String JSONString;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    Log.i("Status: ", "Start Couchbase App");
    if (!Manager.isValidDatabaseName(dbname)) {
        Log.i("Status: ", "Bad couchbase db name!");
        return;
    }
    createManager();
    createCouchdb();
    createDocument(docId);

    Document retrievedDocument = retrieveDocument(docId);
    updateDocument(retrievedDocument);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    //deleteDocument(retrievedDocument);

}

public void createManager() {
    try {
        manager = new Manager(new AndroidContext(getApplicationContext()), Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
        Log.i("createManager", "Couchbase Manager created!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("createManager", "Failed to create Couchbase Manager!");
        return;
    }
}

public void createCouchdb() {
    try {
        couchDb = manager.getDatabase(dbname);
        Log.i("createCouchdb", "Couchbase Database created!");
    } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
        Log.i("createCouchdb", "Failed to create Couchbase Database!");
        return;
    }
}

public void createDocument(String docId) {
    // create some dummy data
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    String currentTimeString = dateFormatter.format(calendar.getTime());
    Poi poi = new Poi("Marker",120.0,120.0, "Marker Category", "Marker Order");

    // put those dummy data together
    Map<String, Object> docContent = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    docContent.put("title", poi.getTitle());
    docContent.put("longitude", poi.getLongitude());
    docContent.put("latitude", poi.getLatitude());
    docContent.put("category", poi.getCategory());
    docContent.put("order", poi.getOrder());

    //docContent.put("poi", poi);
    Log.i("createDocument", "docContent=" + String.valueOf(docContent));


    // create an empty document, add content and write it to the couchDb
    Document document = new Document(couchDb, docId);
    try {
        document.putProperties(docContent);
        Log.i("createDocument: ", "Document written to couchDb named " + dbname + " with ID = " + document.getId());

    } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
        Log.i("createDocument: ", "Failed to write document to Couchbase database!");

    }
}

public Document retrieveDocument(String docId) {
    Document retrievedDocument = couchDb.getDocument(docId);
    Log.i("retrieveDocument", "retrievedDocument Properties=" + String.valueOf(retrievedDocument.getProperties()));
    return retrievedDocument;
}

public void updateDocument(Document doc) {
    Map<String, Object> updatedProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    updatedProperties.putAll(doc.getProperties());
    //updatedProperties.put ("message", "We're having a heat wave!");
    //updatedProperties.put ("temperature", "95");

    try {
        doc.putProperties(updatedProperties);
        Log.i("updateDocument", "updated retrievedDocument=" + String.valueOf(doc.getProperties()));
    } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
        Log.i("updateDocument", "Failed to update document!");

    }

}

public void deleteDocument(Document doc) {
    try {
        doc.delete();
        Log.i("deleteDocument: ", "Document deleted from Couchbase database!");
    } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
        Log.i("deleteDocument: ", "Failed to write delete document from Couchbase database!");
    }
}

private Poi retrievePoi(Database database, String docId) {

    Object poiObj  = null;
    Document retrievedDocument = database.getDocument(docId);
    Log.i( retrieveP + " - ID:", retrievedDocument.getId()); //empty!!!

    Poi p1 = null;
    try{
        p1 = parseDocPoi(retrievedDocument);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.i("exception",e.getMessage());
    }
    Log.d(retrieveP , poiObj.toString());
    //Retrieve the document by id
    return p1;
}

//from retrievePoi
private Poi parseDocPoi(Document d ) {

    Object poiObj;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Map<String, Object> properties = d.getProperties();

    String Title = (String) properties.get("title");
    //String Title = d.getProperty("title").toString();
    String Category = (String) properties.get("category");
    String Order = (String) properties.get("order");

    Double mLatitude = (Double) properties.get("latitude");
    Double mLongitude = (Double) properties.get("longitude");


    Log.i(parseDocPoi + " title: ", Title);
    Log.i(parseDocPoi + " Category: ", Category);
    Log.i(parseDocPoi + " Longitude: ", ""+ Double.toString(mLongitude));
    Log.i(parseDocPoi + " Latitude: ", ""+ Double.toString(mLatitude));
    Log.i(parseDocPoi + " Order: ", Order);


    Poi mPoi = new Poi(Title, mLatitude, mLongitude, Category, Order);
    //String JSONString = gson.toJson(poiObj, Poi.class); //Convert the object to json string using Gson
    //Poi poi = (Poi) poiObj;
    //        gson.fromJson(JSONString, Poi.class); //convert the json string to Poi object
    //Log.i(parseDocPoi + " - JSONString:", JSONString); //empty!!!
    Log.i(parseDocPoi + " getPoiFromDocument ", "jsonString>>>" + mPoi.getCategory()); //Marker Category
    return mPoi;
}

//from OnMapReady
private ArrayList<Poi> retrieveAllPois(Database database) {

    ArrayList<Poi> listOfPois = new ArrayList<Poi>();

    // Let's find the documents that have conflicts so we can resolve them:
    Query query = database.createAllDocumentsQuery();
    query.setAllDocsMode(Query.AllDocsMode.ALL_DOCS);
    QueryEnumerator result = null;
    try {
        result = query.run();
    } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (Iterator<QueryRow> it = result; it.hasNext(); ) {

        QueryRow row = it.next();
        Log.i(retrieveAP, "Query Document ID is: ", row); //empty
        Log.i(retrieveAP, "Query result is: ", row.getDocumentId()); //empty

        //p = parseDocPoi(row.getDocument());
        Log.i( retrieveAP + " - ID:", row.getDocument().getId()); //=78870b85-747d-42c1-ae07-4b0dd96d5fdb
        Document doc;
        doc = retrieveDocument(row.getDocument().getId());
        Log.i(retrieveAP + " - Id:", doc.getProperties().get("_id").toString());
        Log.i(retrieveAP + " - Rev:", doc.getProperties().get("_rev").toString());

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();  // Usually you only need one instance of this per app.
        try {
            JSONString = retrieveDocument(docId).toString();
            Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(JSONString, Map.class);
            Document document = couchDb.getDocument(docId);
            document.putProperties(map);
        } catch (IOException | CouchbaseLiteException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        Poi p = parseDocPoi(row.getDocument());
        Log.i(retrieveAP + " 1 - Category ", p.getCategory());
        Log.i(retrieveAP + " 1 - Title ", p.getTitle());
        Log.i(retrieveAP + " 1 - Order ", p.getOrder());
        Log.i(retrieveAP + " 1 - Latitude ", Double.toString(p.getLatitude()));
        Log.i(retrieveAP + " 1 - Longitude ", Double.toString(p.getLongitude()));

        // Adds a poi to the pois array list.
        Poi PoiObjtect = new Poi(p.getTitle(), p.getLatitude(), p.getLongitude(),p.getCategory(),p.getOrder() ); // Creating a new object
        listOfPois.add(PoiObjtect); // Adding it to the list

        int listSize = listOfPois.size();

        for (int i = 0; i<listOfPois.size(); i++){
            Log.i("Member name: ", listOfPois.get(i).getTitle());
            Log.i("Member name: ", listOfPois.get(i).getCategory());
            Log.i("Member name: ", listOfPois.get(i).getOrder());
            //Log.i("Member name: ", listOfPois.get(i).getLatitude());

        }
    }

    return listOfPois;
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    //String total2 = String.valueOf( poi.getLatitude());
    ArrayList<Poi> pois = retrieveAllPois(couchDb);
    Poi p;
    p = retrievePoi(couchDb,"");
    p.setLatitude(poi.getLatitude());
    p.setLongitude(poi.getLongitude());


    // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
    //LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    LatLng marker = new LatLng(pois.get(0).getLatitude(), pois.get(0).getLongitude());

    //LatLng marker = new LatLng(p.getLatitude(), p.getLongitude());
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marker).title(p.getTitle()));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(marker));

    Log.i("Status: ", "End the App!");
}
}
```

**Poi.java:**

```
public class Poi {

public Double longitude;
public Double latitude;
public String title;
public String category;
public String order;

public Poi(String title, Double longitude, Double latitude, String category, String order) {
    this.title = title;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.category = category;
    this.order = order;
}

public Poi(){}

public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public String getOrder() {
    return order;
}

public void setOrder(String order) {
    this.order = order;
}
}
```

**And the logs:**

```
05-29 17:42:27.086 10581-10581/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
05-29 17:42:27.106 10581-10581/? D/TidaProvider: TidaProvider()
05-29 17:42:27.186 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
05-29 17:42:27.236 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/zzai: Making Creator dynamically
05-29 17:42:27.246 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
05-29 17:42:27.246 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
05-29 17:42:27.336 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 10260000
05-29 17:42:27.346 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 11055246
05-29 17:42:27.556 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure directory: /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/com.example.user.map2/cache
05-29 17:42:27.636 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 W/agl: copyMemory is missing from platform - proto runtime falling back to safer methods.
05-29 17:42:27.646 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/Status:: Start Couchbase App
05-29 17:42:27.726 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/createManager: Couchbase Manager created!
05-29 17:42:27.726 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 W/linker: /data/app/com.example.user.map2-1/lib/arm64/libsqlite3.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6ffffffe arg 0x3de8
05-29 17:42:27.726 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 W/linker: /data/app/com.example.user.map2-1/lib/arm64/libsqlite3.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6fffffff arg 0x2
05-29 17:42:27.726 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 W/linker: /data/app/com.example.user.map2-1/lib/arm64/libcbljavasqlitecustom.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6ffffffe arg 0x1cd20
05-29 17:42:27.726 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 W/linker: /data/app/com.example.user.map2-1/lib/arm64/libcbljavasqlitecustom.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6fffffff arg 0x3
05-29 17:42:27.746 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 E/UCI4C: u_getDataDirectory()=/system/usr/icu
05-29 17:42:27.756 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/createCouchdb: Couchbase Database created!
05-29 17:42:27.756 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/createDocument: docContent={latitude=120.0, order=Marker Order, category=Marker Category, title=Marker, longitude=120.0}
05-29 17:42:27.766 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/createDocument:: Failed to write document to Couchbase database!
05-29 17:42:27.786 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/retrieveDocument: retrievedDocument Properties={_rev=143-248cfa99acba5542fe0126995ccc695c, order=Marker Order, title=Marker, category=Marker Category, longitude=120.0, latitude=120.0, _id=123}
05-29 17:42:27.826 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/updateDocument: updated retrievedDocument={_rev=144-dd4f47e9a74aade50d27da4857a4506e, order=Marker Order, category=Marker Category, title=Marker, longitude=120.0, latitude=120.0, _id=123}
05-29 17:42:27.836 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = true
05-29 17:42:27.836 10581-10665/com.example.user.map2 D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
05-29 17:42:27.846 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 D/Atlas: Validating map...
05-29 17:42:27.856 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 D/ActivityThreadInjector: clearCachedDrawables.
05-29 17:42:27.876 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/RETRIEVE_ALL_POIs: Query Document ID is: 
05-29 17:42:27.876 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/RETRIEVE_ALL_POIs: Query result is: 
05-29 17:42:27.876 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/RETRIEVE_ALL_POIs - ID:: 123
05-29 17:42:27.876 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/retrieveDocument: retrievedDocument Properties={_rev=144-dd4f47e9a74aade50d27da4857a4506e, order=Marker Order, category=Marker Category, title=Marker, longitude=120.0, latitude=120.0, _id=123}
05-29 17:42:27.876 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/RETRIEVE_ALL_POIs - Id:: 123
05-29 17:42:27.876 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/RETRIEVE_ALL_POIs - Rev:: 144-dd4f47e9a74aade50d27da4857a4506e
05-29 17:42:27.906 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/PARSE_DOC_POI getPoiFromDocument: jsonString>>>Marker Category
05-29 17:42:27.906 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/Member name:: Marker
05-29 17:42:27.906 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/RETRIEVE_ALL_POIs: Query Document ID is: 
05-29 17:42:27.906 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/RETRIEVE_ALL_POIs: Query result is: 
05-29 17:42:27.906 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/RETRIEVE_ALL_POIs - ID:: 78870b85-747d-42c1-ae07-4b0dd96d5fdb
05-29 17:42:27.906 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/retrieveDocument: retrievedDocument Properties={_rev=1-7fb403f73a4446d70cf0a21a97e0b10a, _id=78870b85-747d-42c1-ae07-4b0dd96d5fdb}
05-29 17:42:27.906 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/RETRIEVE_ALL_POIs - Id:: 78870b85-747d-42c1-ae07-4b0dd96d5fdb
05-29 17:42:27.906 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/RETRIEVE_ALL_POIs - Rev:: 1-7fb403f73a4446d70cf0a21a97e0b10a
05-29 17:42:27.906 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/PARSE_DOC_POI getPoiFromDocument: jsonString>>>null
05-29 17:42:27.906 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-29 17:42:27.906 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: 
com.example.user.map2, PID: 10581

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double 
java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference
                                                                       at 
com.example.user.map2.Poi.getLatitude(Poi.java:30)
                                                                       at 
com.example.user.map2.MapsActivity.retrieveAllPois(MapsActivity.java:265)
                                                                       at 
com.example.user.map2.MapsActivity.onMapReady(MapsActivity.java:286)
                                                                       at 
com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at 
com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzt$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at 
android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java)
                                                                       at 

com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.aq.a
(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:5)
                                                                       at 


com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bb.run
(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:5)
                                                                       at 
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
                                                                       at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
                                                                       at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
                                                                       at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                       at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                       at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
                                                                       at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
    05-29 17:42:27.916 10581-10581/com.example.user.map2 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10581 SIG: 9
```

Any ideas will be appreceated, thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that you are populating the object `Poi` properly from couchbase?  

You have the `latitude`, `longitude` as `Double` and in getter you have it as `double` so these properties probably are null and in getter because you try to return a `double` instead of `Double` you have `NullPointer` because the `Double` -> `double` will trigger the `doubleValue()` on a null property. 

I think you are not populating the document properly.

Comment: I just changed all to doubles to Doubles, but there is still a NPE in the logs, although they are displayed.

Comment: As I said are you sure that the document is fetched and populate the object properly?